# How to keep class method names that override\implements another method from being obfuscated?

Tags: java, android, proguard

If I have a `Class B` that implements `Interface A` and Proguard isn't aware of the existence of that interface, How can I keep the names of the methods that implements interface A's abstract methods?

Please notice that I want to keep the method names, but I do want their content to be obfuscated.

**Update:**
This is what I have (Please notice the comments):

```
public class MyService extends Service {

   // an anonymous class that implements ServiceConnection 
   private ServiceConnection myConnection = new ServiceConnection()
   {
      // don't change the following method's name
      @Override
      public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service)
      {
          // I want this section to be obfuscated
      }

}
```

I want a general solution for these kind of cases - I don't want to state interfaces names in the ProGuard configuration.

Comment: @Raghunandan the comment you posted is irrelavant !! You answered someone else's question here !! Please find my blog for Progaurd at http://techspreadwithshraddha.wordpress.com/2013/03/26/android-progaurd/

Comment: @Shraddha thanks for reminding. probably opened a wrong tab of my browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Keeping all public class names and keep (prevent obfuscation) of
  their public and protected methods.
- In non-public classes and keep (prevent obfuscation) all public and
  protected methods. This will keep the methods that might implement or extend other methods, from being obfuscated.
- Don't keep the local variables attributes (make
  sure that "LocalVariableTable" and "LocalVariableTypeTable" are not
  stated in the "-keepattributes" option).

So your .pro file should look like this -

```
#Keeping all public class names and keep (prevent obfuscation) of their public and protected methods
-keep public class * {
    public protected <methods>;
}

# Keep (prevent obfuscation) all public and protected methods in non-public classes.
# Notice that the non-public class names will still get obfuscated
-keepclassmembers !public class * {
    public protected <methods>;
}

# Don't keep the local variables attributes (LocalVariableTable and LocalVariableTypeTable are dropped).
-keepattributes Exceptions,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,SourceDir,LineNumberTable,Synthetic,EnclosingMethod,RuntimeVisibleAnnotations,RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations,RuntimeVisibleParameterAnnotations,RuntimeInvisibleParameterAnnotations,AnnotationDefault,InnerClasses,*Annotation*
```

Comment: @RonTesler, How to obfuscate only one class and its public method?

Answer (score 0):

I have writtern a blog for Progaurding the Android application. Please check the link below

http://techspreadwithshraddha.wordpress.com/2013/03/26/android-progaurd/

ProGuard can do what you describe. If you don't want it to rename classes and methods, Please try the following one :

```
-keep,allowshrinking,allowoptimization class * { <methods>; }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear about it - I don't want to specify the interface name. I'm trying to find a general solution. Is it possible?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Notice the ' * ' in the answer, write '*' whenever you want to keep it generic. Please follow the blog it will help you. It has an example for android application

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doing as you suggested, keeps the class name and all the method names, but they also won't get obfuscated.

Comment: I did what you suggested - now all my code is not obfuscated :)

Comment: Ohh, did it, I think in that case I will need to dig it a little more, I will get back to you if I find any solution for the same.